# Three js move object using vector with applied angle

Tags: javascript, vector, three.js, rotation

On keyboard button, I am calling following function. I just want to apply movement on Z-axis. It works perfectly.

```
// declared global Object3D object
function moveRight() {
    v = new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0.01)
    object.position.add(v)
}
```

However, sometimes there is case when model is already rotated.  I am storing this rotation in variable "totalrotation" (in degrees). In that case, I want to move my object in proper direction (not only in z axis). What I have tried was:

```
// declared global Object3D object
// declared global float totalrotation, lets say it is 90 deg
function moveRight() {
    v = new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0.01)
    rads = THREE.Math.degToRad(totalrotation)
    v.applyAxisAngle( new THREE.Vector3(0, 1, 0), rads);
    object.position.add(v)
}
```

But it did not work. Then I was trying furthermore, and just tried dividing rads by number 4:

```
// declared global Object3D object
// declared global float totalrotation, lets say it is 90 deg
function moveRight() {
    v = new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0.01)
    rads = THREE.Math.degToRad(totalrotation) / 4
    v.applyAxisAngle( new THREE.Vector3(0, 1, 0), rads);
    object.position.add(v)
}
```

And it started to work as expected.
Could anyone please explain, why the second code example does not work? In the second example, I am adding correctly rotated vector to my object, and I have no idea why I have to divide the angle by number 4.

**EDIT1: This question can not be solved, because I made mistake in another method, so totalrotation was 4 times bigger as it should. Piece of code without "/ 4" division is working. More info in answer.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I have figured it out. Basically I was incrementing totalrotation in another method accidentally too many times. After button pressed, I wanted to add 1 degree angle, instead, I added 1 degree angle for every object occurence. Four times 1 degree, it is 4, and that is why totalangle had to be devided by 4.
Sorry for confusion, I guess nobody could know it because I did not make this function available. This method:

```
function rotateLeft() { // this method gets invoked by keyboard press
    for (var i = 0; i < objects.length; i++) {
        if (objects[i][1] > 0) {
            totalrotation += 1
            rotateAboutPoint(objects[i][0], new THREE.Vector3(globalXpos, globalYpos, craneZ-1.06), new THREE.Vector3(0, 1, 0), THREE.Math.degToRad(1))
        }
    }
}
```

had to be changed to:

```
function rotateLeft() { // this method gets invoked by keyboard press
    totalrotation += 1
    for (var i = 0; i < objects.length; i++) {
        if (objects[i][1] > 0) {
            rotateAboutPoint(objects[i][0], new THREE.Vector3(globalXpos, globalYpos, craneZ-1.06), new THREE.Vector3(0, 1, 0), THREE.Math.degToRad(1))
        }
    }
}
```